# Issues with using regex in 'gsub'

Tags: ruby, gsub

I am puzzled why this is not working as expected.

```
d = "936589_WI_RAPIDS_STREET_DEPT"
f=d.gsub('/936*[0-9]_/',' ')
# => "936589_WI_RAPIDS_STREET_DEPT"
```

I tested my regex by itself and it gives me the desired output:

```
"WI_RAPIDS_STREET_DEPT"
```

Comment: Please remove the IRB prompts, the code `require "awesome_print"` and the return value of the `d` assignment as these are not necessary for the question. Thanks:)

Comment: OK figured it out.. my syntax was incorrect - d.gsub /936.*[0-9]_/, ""

Comment: Just remove the quotes around the regex.

Comment: Yes, Just realized that gsub needs a regex object and a String as an arguement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gsub` accept a regex object, not a string .

Try:

```
f=d.gsub(/936*[0-9]_/, ' ')
```

And your regex should probably be as below:

```
f=d.gsub(/936[0-9]*_/, ' ')
```

Comment: `gsub` also accepts a string, it just won't parse a regex object from a string : )